# How to copy file to C++ project from output in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I create a console project ,and when I copy a .h file from output to my project,it's just a reference and I want to import the file to the project.

```
1.create Visual C++ project in Visual Studio 2017
2.Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V copy Sales_item.h to head directory from desktop
```

but Sales_item.h always stayed in desktop, I want to import Sales_item.h to my project.
[image: It's always stay in original place]

Comment: "copy a .h file from output to my project" -- huh? Please, provide a list of steps required to reproduce this problem. That's the easiest way to make sure people understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove current Sales_Item.h from project
2. Add this file again by `Project->Add Existing Item` or `Shift + Alt + A` combination. But for this time add file from location you need.